# Unpassed hidden tests in java programs (codefights)

Tags: java, testing

Here is the assignment:

I have 4 input arrays indicating information of different employees

```
String[] names, boolean[] statuses, int[] projects, int[] tasks
```

They will be passed as parameters to the method that I had to write.
The output should be the name of the employee that meets the requirement

**The requirement is:**

- The i^th element of each array belongs to the i^th employee. The number of employees varies
- His/her **statuses** has to be *false* for this employee to be considered for the next condition
- If, for example, the **statuses** of **A** and **B** are false, the one with fewer **tasks**, or the one with **tasks** equivalent to that of the other but having fewer **projects** will be chosen. Do this for all employees.
- Return the **names** (String) of this employee

Example of the arrays maybe like:

```
names = ["John", "Martin"], statuses = [false, false],
projects = [2, 1] and tasks = [16, 5],
```

The output should be:

```
smartAssigning(names, statuses, projects, tasks) = "Martin".
```

And here is my code: (this is only the method)

```
String smartAssigning(String[] names, boolean[] statuses, int[] projects, int[] tasks) {
String name = null;
int task = tasks[0];
int order = 0;
int mainOrder = 0;
int project;
int[] list = new int[names.length];
for (int i = 1; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i] < task && statuses[i] == false) {
        task = tasks[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (task == tasks[i]) {
        list[order] = i;
        order++;
    }
}
project = list[0];
if (order > 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i < order; i++) {
    if (project > projects[list[i]]) {
        project = projects[list[i]];
        mainOrder = list[i];
        }
    }
} else mainOrder = list[0];
return names[mainOrder];

}
```

The problem is I wasn't able to pass 2 out of 11 available tests. But those 2 were hidden. Anyone can give me some suggestions?

Comment: I don't know who's teaching you to do congruent arrays (multiple arrays that hold different info about the same set of things), but you really should look into creating an Employee Class.

Comment: No, I got this one from codefights, a coding website

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:
    String smartAssigning(String[] names, boolean[] statuses, int[] projects, int[] tasks) {

```
    String assignTo = null;
    int minvaluep = projects[0];
    int minvaluepi = 0;
    int minvaluet = tasks[0];
    int minvalueti = 0;
    int duplicate = -1;

    for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        if (statuses[j] == false) {
            if (tasks[j] < minvaluet) {
                minvaluet = tasks[j];
                minvalueti = j;
            }
            assignTo = names[minvalueti];
        }
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < projects.length; k++) {
        for (int l = k + 1; l < projects.length; l++) {
            if (String.valueOf(projects[k]).equals(String.valueOf(projects[l]))) {
                duplicate = k;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
        if (statuses[j] == false) {
            if (tasks[j] < minvaluet) {
                minvaluet = tasks[j];
                minvalueti = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if (duplicate > -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (statuses[i] == false) {
                if (projects[i] < minvaluep) {
                    minvaluep = projects[i];
                    minvaluepi = i;
                }

            }
        }
        assignTo = names[minvaluepi];

    }

    return assignTo;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this question in a coding interview today.
My solution passed all the test cases.
Basically, I created a hashmap with all the given values and sorted the names array according to the requirements.
Here is my solution,

```
String smartAssigning(String[] names, boolean[] statuses, int[] projects, int[] tasks) {

HashMap<String, int[]>map=new HashMap<>();

for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
   int[] obj=new int[3];
   obj[0]=tasks[i];
   obj[1]=projects[i];
   obj[2]= (statuses[i])?1:0;
   map.put(names[i],obj);
}

Arrays.sort(names, (a,b)->
{
  if(map.get(a)[2]==0 && map.get(b)[2]==0)
     if(map.get(a)[0]-map.get(b)[0] == 0)
        return map.get(a)[1]-map.get(b)[1];
     else
        return map.get(a)[0]-map.get(b)[0];
  else
     return (map.get(a)[2]==0)? -1:1;
}
);

return names[0];
}
```